# How can I get the values of data attributes in JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I have next html:

```html
<span data-typeId="123" data-type="topic" data-points="-1" data-important="true" id="the-span"></span>
```

Is it possible to get the attributes that beginning with `data-`, and use it in the **JavaScript** code like code below? For now I get `null` as result.

```js
document.getElementById("the-span").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var json = JSON.stringify({
        id: parseInt(this.typeId),
        subject: this.datatype,
        points: parseInt(this.points),
        user: "H. Pauwelyn"
    });
});
```

Comment: In nowadays (2019) it is also possible to use node's dataset property with SVG nodes (!), see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57540151/287948)  or use [with D3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57539693/287948).

Answer (score 356, accepted):

You need to access the [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```
document.getElementById("the-span").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var json = JSON.stringify({
    id: parseInt(this.dataset.typeid),
    subject: this.dataset.type,
    points: parseInt(this.dataset.points),
    user: "Luïs"
  });
});
```

Result:

```
// json would equal:
{ "id": 123, "subject": "topic", "points": -1, "user": "Luïs" }
```

Comment: Bear in mind that according to MDN the datasets standard won't work for Internet Explorer < 11. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#Issues
"To support IE 10 and under you need to access data attributes with getAttribute() instead."

Comment: any idea how this would work with typescript? since in typescript this gives an error, **object maybe undefined**

Comment: Should be noted that if data parameter is writen in html using kebab-case its still gone be auto casted into camelCase

For example if we make <div data-item-id="0"></div>

Then we get its by element.dataset.itemId instead of element.dataset.item-id cause "-" is not valid character in property name

Answer (score 170):

Because the `dataset` property wasn't supported by Internet Explorer until version 11, you may want to use `getAttribute()` instead:

```
document.getElementById("the-span").addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log(this.getAttribute('data-type'));
});
```

[Dataset documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

[getAttribute documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Answer (score 63):

You could also grab the attributes with the [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method which will return the value of a specific HTML attribute.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('the-span');

const typeId = elem.getAttribute('data-typeId');
const type   = elem.getAttribute('data-type');
const points = elem.getAttribute('data-points');
const important = elem.getAttribute('data-important');

console.log(`typeId: ${typeId} | type: ${type} | points: ${points} | important: ${important}`
);
```

```html
<span data-typeId="123" data-type="topic" data-points="-1" data-important="true" id="the-span"></span>
```

Answer (score 56):

You can access it as

```
element.dataset.points
```

etc. So in this case: `this.dataset.points`

Answer (score 18):

if you are targeting data attribute in Html element,

`document.dataset` will not work

you should use

```
document.querySelector("html").dataset.pbUserId
```

or

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].dataset.pbUserId
```

Answer (score 6):

### Modern browsers accepts HTML and SVG DOMnode.dataset

Using  [pure Javascript's DOM-node *dataset* property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement/dataset).

It is an [old Javascript standard for HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Specifications) (since Chorme 8 and Firefox 6) but [**new for SVG**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement/dataset) (since year 2017 with Chorme 55.x and Firefox 51)... It is not a problem for SVG because in nowadays (2019) the version's *usage share* is dominated by modern browsers.

The values of dataset's key-values are pure strings, but **a good practice is to adopt JSON string format** for non-string datatypes, to parse it by `JSON.parse()`.

### Using the *dataset* property in any context

Code snippet to *get* and *set* key-value *datasets* at HTML and SVG contexts.

```js
console.log("-- GET values --")
var x = document.getElementById('html_example').dataset;
console.log("s:", x.s );
for (var i of JSON.parse(x.list)) console.log("list_i:",i)

var y = document.getElementById('g1').dataset;
console.log("s:", y.s );
for (var i of JSON.parse(y.list)) console.log("list_i:",i)

console.log("-- SET values --");
y.s="BYE!"; y.list="null";
console.log( document.getElementById('svg_example').innerHTML )
```

```html
<p id="html_example" data-list="[1,2,3]" data-s="Hello123">Hello!</p>
<svg id="svg_example">
  <g id="g1" data-list="[4,5,6]" data-s="Hello456 SVG"></g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

Circa 2019, using jquery, this can be accessed using `$('#DOMId').data('typeId')` where `$('#DOMId')` is the jquery selector for your span element.

Answer (score -2):

Example:

```html
<input data-default-value="Default Value">Name</input>
```

```js
inputEl.getAttribute("data-default-value")
```

→ returns: Default Value

Answer (score -4):

```
document.getElementById('selectTbl').addEventListener('change', function () {
    $("#selectTbl").val();
    var style = $(this).val() == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('TblAdmin').style.display = style;

    var style = $(this).val() == 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('TblMech').style.display = style;

    var style = $(this).val() == 3 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('TblUser').style.display = style;

    var style = $(this).val() == 4 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('TblBiz').style.display = style;
});
```

Sorry to interrupt I think you already got the answer. Can someone help for me?
Here I want to display the div which is `TblAdmin`, `TblMech`, `TblUser`, `TblBiz`. I'm currently using NiceSelect but inside the select dropdown it has data value attribute. It actually not select but list-item inside unordered-list.

Like picture shown here,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VyHDMb1Gl4PYBe19XZt1Z8Z-2OLAS1mx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it is better to add this as seoarate question so it will be properly answered

Comment: already but no one answered...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987887/get-value-from-niceselect/71987971?noredirect=1#comment127214672_71987971

Answer (score -10):

Try this instead of your code:

```
var type=$("#the-span").attr("data-type");
alert(type);
```

Comment: Asker didn't mention jQuery, this isn't even good jQuery for this purporse. Should be `.data('type');` instead.

Comment: And on top of that the suggestion to use this "instead of your code" is far too broad; the Asker would want to keep the event handling set-up, and `JSON` result, not an `alert`  of the `data-type` attribute.

Comment: this is jquery, not pure javascript.

Answer (score -10):

You can actually use JQuery to accomplish that in a very easy way

```
$(document).on('click', '.the-span', function(){

let type = $(this).data("type");

});
```

Comment: With the explosion of frameworks such as Vue, React and Angular it goes against most of these frameworks practices to use jQuery. If the OP is using one of these then they should actively be avoiding jQuery. Additionally, they asked for it in JavaScript rather than jQuery which is why I've votes this down.