# Connecting MVC to knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple MVC model called `Invitation`, it looks like this:

```
    public class Invitation
    {
        public string InvitedUserDisplayName { get; set; }
        public string InvitedUserEmailAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to create an user interface in the `View`, using knockout.js. Where the user can input value for the 2 fields, as well as press a button that sends the invite (calling an invitation method inside my Controller, passing the `Invitation` Object the user just specified.

I cannot find any solid documentation for beginners that explains this basic process. What I have so far is kind of a mess:

```
@Model = ViewModel.Invitation

<script src="~/lib/knockout/dist/knockout.js"></script>

@model Invitation
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SendInvite" method="post">
    Email: <input asp-for="InvitedUserEmailAddress" data-bind="value: invitedUserDisplayName"/> <br />
    Display Name: <input asp-for="InvitedUserDisplayName" data-bind="value: invitedUserEmailAddress"/> <br />
    <button data-bind="click: sendInvitation">Send Invite</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        invitedUserDisplayName: @Model.InvitedUserDisplayName,
        invitedUserEmailAddress @Model.InvitedUserEmailAddress

        this.sendInvitation = function () {
            //call controller action, passing the newly created Invitation. 
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Comment: Turn your model into Json, write it somewhere then read it using javascript on the client side. Json is your go to c#-Javadscript information exchange format

Comment: @Liam Do you know if there is some super basic documentation on how to do all this? From start to finish. I am very new to frontend dev.

Comment: I've added some brief code examples of what you need to be thinking about. This isn't extensive as the subject is quite broad but it will hopefully point you in the right direction

Comment: thanks, should be able to figure the rest out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend something along the lines of this (there are other ways to do this).

In your controller turn your object into JSON (I'm using the Json.Net library as it's the best), see [Turn C# object into a JSON string in .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4) for more info

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
   var viewModel;
   var objectIWantToUse;

   //this is a string!
   viewModel.objectIWantToUseJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectIWantToUse);

   return View(viewModel);
}
```

then in your view:

```
@Model = viewModel

<script src="~/lib/knockout/dist/knockout.js"></script>

<div id="someDOM" data-modeljson="@viewModel.objectIWantToUseJson">
...
```

Now your knockout can read the JSON using [JSON.Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), see [Deserializing a JSON into a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487167/deserializing-a-json-into-a-javascript-object) and [get data attributes in JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760520/get-data-attributes-in-javascript-code):

```
var domElement = document.getElementById('someDOM');
var viewModelFromJson = JSON.Parse(domElement.dataset.modeljson);

ko.applyBindings(viewModelInJson);
```

Comment: Where does viewModelInJson come from?

Comment: I misread your question @Green_qaue `viewModelFromJson` is just a variable to hold the object created from the json?