# Acquiring the JSON value of a data attribute, and search for matching Json key -> data attribute in a specific DOM element

Tags: javascript, json

I have an HTML element with a data attribute:

```
<a href="#" data-trigger="{ "rem": "albatros", "ap":1 }'">Remove</a>
<div data-container>
    <p>lorem ipsum<p>
    <p data-rem></p>
</div>
```

1.

in the `data-trigger` sometimes(not always) I send a value:

I want to gather all elements that have the attribute `data-trigger`:

```
document.querySelectorAll(['data-trigger']).forEach(function (trigger, index) {
```

and for each of this `trigger` to get the DOM and JSON value and parse it:

```
dom = trigger    
value = JSON.parse(trigger.getAttribute('data-trigger'));
```

I get the `DOM` reference but for the value I always get `null`

By using `getAttribute` do I call again in the DOM ?

2. Looping thru `data-container` search for elements which have the attributes one of the keys found in JSON.parse and set their value, the value of the key.

For example:

```
<p data-rem>albatros</p>
```

Comment: I believe that this is already answered in this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760520/get-data-attributes-in-javascript-code

Comment: @MarlonBarcarol, possible, for the first part, I will check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is currently stopping your script in its tracks is the selector inside `querySelectorAll()`.

It should be `'[data-trigger]'`, **not** `['data-trigger']`.

After you fix it, you'll be able to get all elements with a `data-trigger` attribute. However, the string you placed in `data-trigger` attribute won't parse as a JavaScript object (as you probably expect). Your best bet would be to replace quotes with double quotes and double quotes with quotes, making it a valid JSON string and parse it:

```
<a href="#" data-trigger='{"rem": "albatros"}'>Remove</a>
```

```js
JSON.parse(elem.getAttribute('data-trigger')) // where elem is the DOM element above
```

You haven't been exactly clear on what the purpose of this script is but, assuming you want to find a list of DOM elements having `'data-'+foundKey` equal to `foundVal`, you could make the following selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-'+foundKey+'="'+foundVal+'"]').forEach(function(el, i){
  console.log(el, i);
})
```

... but in your case that wouldn't do anything, because you don't have any element with

```
<x data-rem="albatros"></x>
```

Here's a working example of what I'm talking about, applied to your markup:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-trigger]').forEach(function (trigger, index) {
  const triggerProp = JSON.parse(trigger.getAttribute('data-trigger')),
        foundKey = Object.keys(triggerProp)[0],
        foundVal = triggerProp[Object.keys(triggerProp)[0]],
        targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-'+foundKey+']').forEach(function(target, index) {
    console.log(target, 'key:'+foundKey, 'val:'+target.getAttribute('data-'+foundKey));
  });
})
```

```html
<a href="#" data-trigger='{"rem": "albatros"}'>Remove</a>
<div data-container>
    <p>lorem ipsum<p>
    <p data-rem="test"></p>
</div>
```

Do note that it only works because the value of `data-trigger` is valid JSON. If it were not, it would fail miserably. You could guard your script from this risk by a try/catch function that would test the value as JSON first. Another alternative is to use a library that parses relaxed JSON.

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid JSON String

```
<a href="#" data-trigger="{'rem': 'albatros'}">Remove</a>
```

Try:

```
<a href="#" data-trigger='{"rem": "albatros"}'>Remove</a> <!-- Double quotes in JSON -->
```

Then:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[data-trigger]").forEach(function (trigger, index) {
  var val = JSON.parse(trigger.getAttribute('data-trigger'));
  for( key in val){ //Loop through (JSON-)Object
   setInnerElements(val[key], key);
  }
  
});

function setInnerElements(val,key){

document.querySelectorAll("[data-container] > [data-"+ key +"]").forEach(function (el, index) {
   el.innerHTML = val;
  })
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-trigger='{"rem": "albatros", "foo":"test1", "bar":"test2"}'>Remove</a>
<div data-container>
<p>lorem ipsum<p>
<p data-rem></p>
<p>lorem ipsum<p>
<p data-foo></p>
<p>lorem ipsum<p>
<p data-bar></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, and for the second part, what is a efficient way to search for elements that have an attribute name equal with the key in JSON ?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: in JSON, can be multiple key that I don't know prior, so I need to loop in Json an then check, but I think doing loop in loops(json and inside doom loop) is not very efficient, so I'm searching for something optimized; in your example you target just one key

Comment: The real value of such methods is when you don't know in advance what they keys might be. To iterate through all enumerable properties of your parsed JSON, you'll find `Object.keys()` quite useful: `elem[Object.keys(elem)][0]` or use a `for` loop on the `Object.keys()` array, if you have more than one key-value pairs.

Comment: Edited my answer