# Access data from HTML link using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say that I have this simple link with data inside:

```
<a href="#" data-value="Something" onclick="testFunction(this)">X</a>
```

How can I access this `data-value` using JavaScript or jQuery.

I tried this but didn't work:

```
function testFunction(element){
    console.log(element.value);
}
```

or this

```
function testFunction(element){
    console.log(element.data('value'));
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Hi Harun, the dataset property is your friend  please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760520/get-data-attributes-in-javascript-code

Comment: If you want to use jQuery take a look to https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/1277/