# how can send data-* attr to a js function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

i need to use jplayer add to playlist in my joomla website and i will when user click on icon of play , jquery get the data-mp3 and data-name and data-poster from  tag link and add to above function to add that sound in player
please help me how did it?
i cant get data-* attribute and send to myplaylist.add function for add that sound data to playlist of jplayer

```
$("#playlist-equivalent-1-a"). click(function() {
    myPlaylist.add({
        title:"title",
        artist:"artist",
        mp3:"url",
        poster: "url"
    }, true);
});
```

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute
and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760520/get-data-attributes-in-javascript-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get data attributes in JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760520/get-data-attributes-in-javascript-code)

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck, jQuery has a built-in function for retrieving `data-*` attributes:
https://api.jquery.com/data/.

Example: Get the mp3 title and artist from an anchor tag

```js
$('#datatag').click(function() {
  $('#output').text($('#datatag').data('title') + ' from ' + $('#datatag').data('artist') + ' is a really good song!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a data-artist="De Jeugd van Tegenwoordig" data-title="Sterrenstof" id="datatag">Click me to reveal my data.</a><br>
<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: It's not a correct answer. Implement your code to the OP example. OP knows about `data-*`.

Comment: i need send that attr to myPlaylist.add and run this function after it
for example

    myPlaylist.add({
        title:"Sterrenstof ",
        artist:"De Jeugd van Tegenwoordig ",
        mp3:"your url",
        poster: "your url"
    }, true);

and after set this attr run this function

Comment: @mohammadjavadjabbari could you clarify a bit more? If I got it right you want to:
1. Get data attributes from some element
2. Pass them to `myPlaylist.add`
3. Run a function (which one?)

Comment: @Fdebijl first i need Get data attributes from some element  then Pass them to myPlaylist.add then run myPlaylist.add function because this function add that music data to my playlist of jplayer
--  jplayer with playlist demo : http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/ 
-- A project similar to my topic : http://zakerin.ir