# JavaScript: how to get content of an attribute of a tag

Tags: javascript, attributes

When I run this:

```js
document.activeElement
```

I get this:

```html
<span id="123" data-caption="ABC">
```

How to get the content of the `data-caption` tag?
In this case, I would like to see the string `ABC`.

Many thanks.

Comment: so read the data attribute?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760520/how-can-i-get-the-values-of-data-attributes-in-javascript-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it in the following way:

```
document.activeElement.attributes['data-caption'].value;
```

P.S. consider using a fallback if the element does not have a `data-caption` property

Comment: missing the real way of getting it, also not sure why you added jQuery when no mention of Jquery

Comment: @AzizaKasenova Follow up question, if you don't mind. How to save this result in Java variable?

Comment: I tried this:
`String result = js.executeScript("document.activeElement.attributes['data-caption'].value;").toString();`
It didn't work

Comment: Im not sure of Java