# Get data-value from niceSelect to display hidden div

Tags: javascript

I have a problem after I used the [niceSelect](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VyHDMb1Gl4PYBe19XZt1Z8Z-2OLAS1mx/view?usp=sharing). Before this I just use simple Javascript to show and hide table. Before I used the niceSelect it works fine because the `value` is just `value`. But after I used niceSelect the `value element` inside the select option become `data-value`

HTML:

```
<select class="wide" id="selectTbl">
       <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
       <option value="1">Admin</option>
       <option value="2">Mechanic</option>
       <option value="3">User</option>
       <option value="4">Business</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('selectTbl').addEventListener('change', function () {
    $("#selectTbl").val();
    var style = $(this).val() == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('TblAdmin').style.display = style;

    var style = $(this).val() == 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('TblMech').style.display = style;

    var style = $(this).val() == 3 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('TblUser').style.display = style;

    var style = $(this).val() == 4 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('TblBiz').style.display = style;
});
```

Can someone help for me?
Here I want to display the div which is `TblAdmin`, `TblMech`, `TblUser`, `TblBiz`. I'm currently using NiceSelect but inside the select dropdown it has data value attribute. It actually not select but list-item inside unordered-list.

Like picture shown here,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VyHDMb1Gl4PYBe19XZt1Z8Z-2OLAS1mx/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see the issue. "change" doesn't work because it's no longer a normal 'select'. You have to detect clicks and then check the value.

But I suggest you don't use this library, it seems abandoned and it's very limited, not enough methods. Also jquery is not very used nowdays.

But if you want to use the library you could do something like:

```
    $(document).on('click.nice_select', '.nice-select .option:not(.disabled)', function() {
      let val = $("#selectTbl").val()

      var style = val == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
      document.getElementById('TblAdmin').style.display = style;
  
      var style = val == 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
      document.getElementById('TblMech').style.display = style;
  
      var style = val == 3 ? 'block' : 'none';
      document.getElementById('TblUser').style.display = style;
  
      var style = val == 4 ? 'block' : 'none';
      document.getElementById('TblBiz').style.display = style;
    })
```

Comment: I want to get the value from the select option which before I used niceSelect it just value but after I used it. They become data-value so my javascript didn't get the value. U know what I mean.

Comment: How to get the data-value from the niceSelect?

Comment: Try $('id').val() or read this https://github.com/hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select/issues/72

Comment: so from my code `this.value` change to `$('id').val()`. right?

Comment: Because when the data-value is 1 or 2 or 3 the id for the div is display block

Comment: sorry. my javascript skill not good enough

Comment: Give the element an id, so if it's called my_select then do $("#my_select").val()  Or if it's inside the change callback do $(this).val()

Comment: ouh okay. I'll tried

Comment: Still not working. I think because after use the niceselect the select became `uo` `li` not select anymore

Comment: I suggest using normal select. You can style it: https://www.sliderrevolution.com/resources/css-select-styles/

Comment: Hahaha. I'm just thinking of that too so complicated using niceselect. So, now i'm using one of those and it works right away. Thank you for your help @madprops

Comment: Because my intention in first place is just to style the select dropdown only. Didn't expect it is so complicated

Answer (score 0):

```
// NiceSelect plugin
      $(document).ready(function(){
 
        $('#selectTbl').niceSelect();


      });

   document.getElementById('selectTbl').addEventListener('change', function () {
    $("#selectTbl").val();
    var style = $(this).val() == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('TblAdmin').style.display = style;

    var style = $(this).val() == 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('TblMech').style.display = style;

    var style = $(this).val() == 3 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('TblUser').style.display = style;

    var style = $(this).val() == 4 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('TblBiz').style.display = style;
});
```

Is this correct? @madprops

Comment: I'tried it didn't work