# Making js pick up HTML code inside data attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of html code in data attribute.

```
<a href="#" data-type="video" data-video='<div class="wrapper"><div class="video-wrapper"><video id="player" playsinline width="960" class="pswp__video" controls data-poster="img/poster.jpg"><source src="video/soulmv-low.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div></div>'></a>
```

Is there any way to make js pick up the code inside data attribute and modify it, as normal?

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for exactly. What are you trying to do? Read the attribute and what?

Comment: Why would there be HTML inside an attribute? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would expect HTML within an attribute to itself be invalid HTML.  At the very least it should be HTML-encoded as a string.  Though even then I suspect there's a better way to achieve whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Basically im trying to make js parse the code inside data attribute and change it as it was a normal code from html body... Sorry, Im not super experienced in js, so might have messed up the explanation :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the values of data attributes in JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760520/how-can-i-get-the-values-of-data-attributes-in-javascript-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load an `html` as an `DOM Element` to modify is easily instead of an string, you could do the following:

```
const link = document.querySelector('a')

const dataVideoAttribute = link.getAttribute('data-video')

const dataVideoElement = createElementFromString(dataVideoAttribute)
```

*The helper function to create JS Object is descrbied bellow*

```js
/**
 * Create a new HTML Object from an HTML code as string
 * and returns the object.
 * 
 * @params elementAsString: HTML code as a raw string
 *
 * @returns object: HTML Element created from raw string
 */
function createElementFromString(elementAsString) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = elementAsString.trim();

  // Change this to div.childNodes to support multiple top-level nodes.
  return div.firstChild;
}
```

then, you can do normal routines with your JS code, for exmaple:

```
dataVideoElement.setAttribute('new-att', '1')
```

If you want to update and save on html attributes you could:

```js
link.getAttribute('data-video', dataVideoElement.outerHTML)
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the data attribute, for example if the attribute is `data-type="video"`

```
const type = document.getElementById('item1').dataset.type;
```

To set it

```
document.getElementById('item1').dataset.type = "mp3"
```